# Intersection of two django model?

Tags: python, django

I have two models and I want to find out the common sets of values on the basis of their ids

First model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# WE ARE AT MODELS/UNIVERSITIES

class Universities(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name", max_length=255, help_text="")
    abbreviation = models.CharField(db_column="abbreviation", max_length=255, help_text="")
    address = models.CharField(db_column="address", max_length=255, help_text="")
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    updatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column="updatedBy",help_text="Logged in user updated by ......")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        get_latest_by = 'createdAt'
        db_table = 'universities'
```

And the other model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models



class NewsUniversityMappings(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    newsMappingId = models.IntegerField( db_column='newsMappingId' ,max_length=11, help_text="")
    universityId = models.IntegerField( db_column='universityId', max_length=11, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'news_university_mappings'
```

Now, in my views, i have created objects for both models:

```
def add_promoter_news(request, mapping_id=None, news_virtual_id=None):
    try:
        university_all_list = Universities.objects.using("cms").all
        published_university_list = NewsUniversityMappings.objects.using("cms").filter(newsMappingId=news_virtual_id).all()
```

I want to find the common of both the models on the basis of in of `Universities` model and `universityId` of `NewsUniversityMappings` model.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this is what you want, but:

```
def add_promoter_news(request, mapping_id=None, news_virtual_id=None):
    try:
        # Get that queryset
        published_university_list = NewsUniversityMappings.objects.using("cms").filter(newsMappingId=news_virtual_id).all()
        # Get list of distinct universityIds
        published_university_IDS_list = published_university_list.values_list('universityId',flat=True).distinct()
        # Get queryset of all Universities
        university_all_list = Universities.objects.using("cms").all()
        # Get queryset of universities with ids on previous list
        university_list = university_all_list.filter(id__in=published_university_IDS_list)
```

Now in `university_list` you have only `Universities` with ID, that was somewhere in universityId variable of at least one of `NewsUniversityMappings`.
Is that it?

Comment: This is what i need but here university_list = university_all_list.filter(id__in=published_university_IDS_list) it shows error saying 'function' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Right, forgot parentheses in `university_all_list = Universities.objects.using("cms").all()`, of course function `all` has no 'filter'. Try edited answer.